# Mongoose Loop with Callbacks

Tags: node.js, callback, mongoose

I have such code in my Express/Node/Mongoose app (coffeescript)

```
module.exports.doStuff = (req, res, next) ->
  counter = 0

   Cars.find 'tesla', (err, result) ->

    Animals.count Someparameters, (err, result1) ->
      #do Stuff To Result1 

      calcSome = (start = 0) ->
        start++

        Bikes.find Someparameters, (err, result2) ->
          result.forEach (parsedDoc) ->
            #do Stuff To Result1 Result2 etc

            Dogs.get Someparameters, (err, result3) ->
              #recurse
              calcSome start if start < parsedDataCount
              if start = someGuardValue
                  res.status(202).send
                    status     : 'OK'
                    error      : 'Zeilen erfolgreich berechnet.'
                    type       : 'success'
                    parsedDocs :  parsedDocs
                  return
              return
      # Trigger Recursion
      calcSome start if start < counter
    return
```

Now I get headers send twice errors, obviously the callbacks are fired asynchronously. I need to call `Bikes` after `Animals` and `Dogs` after `Bikes` in order to maniplate data. And I need the recursino for other reasons. Then when everything is done, one single `res.status(202)` needs to be send back to the API requestor. Any ideas how to achieve? I am currently looking into async library but am unsure how to approach my specific problem.

Comment: In your case, if you want to send the `response` just after the `forEach` loop has finished, use [`async.each`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#each-arr-iterator-callback), and send the response in the optional callback. If you want to make sure the next iteration is called only after the previous one finished, use `async.eachSeries`, which has the same signature.

Comment: Splendit. In case you can wrap that answer with my code above I will give you the answer, otherwise I will do it later. cheers

Comment: I should add, the forEach needs to iterate multiple times and is part of the recursion, only when the recursion is finished I want the response to be send (once alltogether only).

Comment: Ok, so make your recursive function in a way that it accepts a callback that is going to be called only at the end of the recursion. Then, pass the `done` callback to it. This way you'll guarantee the expected behavior.